# Silent alternative to 3A relay to be controlled with Arduino

Tags: arduino, relay

I wanted an alternative to relay which I can control with an Arduino since a relay is too loud.

I already have a cd4066 bilateral switch but it isn't working in my case because it leaks current.

So was looking for an alternative which is silent and should be able to handle 5V at 3A and be controlled with an Arduino.

Comment: It's really hard to imagine that a relay is "too loud" for this application. From a relay you should hear a muted _tick_ once when you turn it on, and once when you turn it off.

Comment: Why can't you just plug in the phone and let it look after itself? The battery charger is in the phone. You just have to supply 5 V. Please avoid 'bcoz' speak and capitalise words properly ('Arduino') to make your posts more readable. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: There are miniature relays which are not rated for usage on mains voltage but can handle 3A no problem, these switch very silently. You could also use a MOSFET (search this site on how to do that). **Both solution assume you supply the Arduino and charge the phone from the same 5 V !!!**

Comment: And yes what Transistor says: there is really no need to switch off the 5 V to your phone at all. Now with the Arduino and the relay you'd be useing **more** power. Phones have charging circuits which stop charging when the battery is full. If there wasn't then the battery will start to smoke and/or catch fire. So that's why all phones have a charging chip.

Comment: If you *really* want something silent, look into the aptly named `solid-state relay`.

Comment: @user2943160: SSR will probably have an unacceptable voltage drop.

Comment: Thank  You guys for all of your replies. I wanted to attach a PIR sensor to an Arduino and then assume, it would normally charge the phone, but as soon as PIR sensor detects motion, it would simply stop charging for 1 seconds and then continue with its charging. I already developed the code for it. Just wanted the solution to switch, which in my case I am using a CD4066 IC, which doesn't seem to work well in my case, because it leaks current and doesnt break off the current completely.
Need it for my project, hence i want it to stay completely silent.

Comment: @aquib4shaikh: The only reason I can think of doing this is that it's the only means you can think of to detect PIR activity on your phone: detect charging interruption. Is this correct?

Comment: @Transistor     Yeah kinda, actually I am thinking of something else, i just want that first. Its a part of my project. If i succeed in what i am trying to do, I ll showcase it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you switching AC or DC?

If DC than you just need a big MOSFET like BUZ11 or IRLZ44N [connected as shown here](http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/).

If AC than you can use a [triac+optotriac](http://learning.grobotronics.com/2013/07/control-ac-with-triac/).

Comment: Simply want to switch 5v DC at 3 Amps. Essentially a charger for a tablet.

Comment: @filo: Link only answers are not good as they are useless if the link dies. We recommend that you add enough info into your answer so that it stands on its own.

Comment: @aquib4shaikh:  Why can't you stand the reassuring click of a relay?

Comment: @EMFields      I just want it to stay completely silent because i want to implement it in my project which is kinda complicated for my age. Currently in third year of my diploma in Computer Engineering. Using an Arduino too. Code for Arduino is ready, just final step is to find an alternative for relay which is completely silent and can switch upto 5V at 3 Amps.

Comment: @filo          So according to that any MOSFET would work for me?
And also can i use an IRF 540 in my case?
Will it charge normally as if i am plugged into a power source normally. 
I can tolerate if charge speed is less because anyways tablet will stay hooked up to a power source 24x7.
So can i use an IRF 540 in my case?

Comment: @filo          I am switching 5V DC at 3 Amps. 
Will BUZ11 work in my case as i want to control it with arduino uno (5 volts)

Comment: Yes it will. If you read the datasheet of BUZ11 you will find out that it can conduct up to 30A, while switching up to 50V.

Answer (score 0):

A 4066 won't work as a 3 ampere switch:

[image]

Comment: Okay thank you.. I am kinda newbie to electronics. So please suggest me what shall i use in my case to switch 5V at 3 amps?